# Linq For Each - Need Advice

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, list

I have this block of code.

```
var foundAppointments = ServiceLink.FindAppointments(User, SiteSecureKey);    
var MondayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)).ToList();
```

Now I have a global list which I add each days appointments too e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wed etc..

Then I run this:

```
Appointments.Add(MondayAppointments); ..........
```

Is there any whay I can run the Monday through Sunday appointments than having to write.

```
var TuesdayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)).ToList();
var WednesdayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)).ToList();
var ThursdayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y =>y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)).ToList();
var FridayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)).ToList();
var SaturdayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)).ToList();
var SundayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)).ToList();
Appointments.Add(TuesdayAppointments);
Appointments.Add(WednesdayAppointments);
Appointments.Add(ThursdayAppointments);
Appointments.Add(FridayAppointments);
Appointments.Add(SaturdayAppointments);
Appointments.Add(SundayAppointments);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`DayOfWeek` Enumeration documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx): _"If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Sunday`) to six (which indicates `DayOfWeek.Saturday`)"_.

Comment: Is Appointments and MondayAppointments is same type of list? If Yes the use Appointments .AddRange(MondayAppointments);
Make sure Appointments is initialized..

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It seems like you have a list, and you split it up and put it together, ie a reordering? Why not just use `OrderBy()`? Ie `var orderedAppointments = foundAppointments.OrderBy(ap => ap.StartDate);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate over values from `DayOfWeek` enum and get appointments of each day:

```
var days = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
foreach (DayOfWeek dayOfWeek in days)
{
    var dayAppointments = foundAppointments.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)).ToList();
    Appointments.Add(dayAppointments);
}
```

If you need Monday to be first, then sort days:

```
var days = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>()
               .OrderBy(d => d == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
               .ThenBy(d => d);
```

BTW why you are adding appointments day by day? Looks like you can add all at once. If you want to add appointments in order starting from Monday:

```
var appintmentsToAdd = foundAppointments
     .SelectMany(x => x)
     .OrderBy(a => a.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
     .ThenBy(a => a.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek)
     .ToList();

Appointments.Add(appintmentsToAdd);
```

Comment: The reason I dont want to put them out in one massive list is i have several data tables representing each day which would mean more linq queries.

Comment: @TheMonkeyMan sorry, didn't get how one list can cause more queries. Anyway, first solution uses loop for adding appointments day by day

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enum.GetValues` to get all possible `DayOfWeek` values:

```
var days = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>().ToArray();
```

And `AddRange` to add more than one element to `Appointments` at once:

```
var foundAppointments = ServiceLink.FindAppointments(User, SiteSecureKey);    
Appointments.AddRange(days.Select(d => foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == d)).ToList());
```

Or just create `Appointments` directly from your query:

```
var Appointments.AddRange(days.Select(d => foundAppointments.SelectMany(x=>x.Where(y => y.StartTime.Date.DayOfWeek == d)).ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>();

var appointmentsOnDaysOfWeek = daysOfWeek
    .GroupJoin(
        foundAppointments,
        dayOfWeek => dayOfWeek,
        appointment => appointment.StartDate.DayOfWeek,
        (day, appointments) => new
        {
            Day = day,
            Appointments = appointments.ToList()
        })
    .OrderBy(appointmentsOnDay => appointmentsOnDay.Day)
    .Select(appointmentsOnDay => appointmentsOnDay.Appointments);

Appointments.AddRange(appointmentsOnDaysOfWeek);
```

**Update**:
I didn't pay attension to ordering by days when monday should be first. To fix it replace

```
    .OrderBy(appointmentsOnDay => appointmentsOnDay.Day)
```

with

```
    .OrderBy(appointmentsOnDay => appointmentsOnDay.Day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    .ThenBy(appointmentsOnDay => appointmentsOnDay.Day)
```